# How can I check for stored procedure consistency across multiples servers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got a stored procedure on 10 distinct servers, how can I check across all servers for stored procedure consistency?

I'm currently pulling the definition for each server manually, and comparing it in notepad++ compare tool.

It's quite time consuming, and surely I'm not the first one to have this problem.

Comment: Red gate is tool to compare script files and databases schema http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Answer (score 7):

[Kankuru](http://www.kankuru.fr/) is a great and FREE monitoring tool for SQL Server developed here in France. Aside from its monitoring capabilities, it also has a DB compare tool that is easy and simple to use.

It will not only show you if your stored procedures, tables, indexes, types, etc. exist on two servers, but also what those differences are between those two servers.

[image]

Here is another compare screen

[image]

It's very easy to use and as mentioned before, won't cost you a dime.

To setup Kankuru

1. Create an empty database in some SQL Server called Kankuru. The kankuru database just stores configuration information and some history and its very compact.
2. Start Kankuru and from the Home Menu select Configuration

[image]

3. Configure kankuru to use the server\instance and database that you just created.

[image]

There is [documentation](http://www.kankuru.fr/blog.aspx), but its in French. Google translate will be able to get you through one way or another.

Comment: Ooh! Well this looks interesting. Although I'm very much an advocate for RedGate's SQL Compare, I will definitely have a look at this

Comment: @Craig do we have any help content available for this tool as for every server connection it says "The selected database is not a valid Kankuru Database"

Comment: Hello @aasim.abdullah, I updated my answer with some configuration information

Comment: To setup Kankuru, at the first start, you must specify an available SQL-Server instance (you can use SQL Express for example). You must be sysadmin on this instance. You must give a database name which doesn't exist. Kankuru will create its own database. @CraigEfrein : thank you very much for advertising :) **Edit:** The documentation is there but it's only in French: [Configuration de la base Kankuru](http://wiki.kankuru.fr/wiki/9/configuration-de-la-base-kankuru)

Comment: Hello, yeah my pleasure. Been using your software for about a year. Kankuru is épatant!!

Answer (score -1):

One option to consider is to use SQLCMD to execute code on multiple servers from a single source.  You further could log the process for each server by qualifying a distinct log file on each instance calling the code.

Comment: So use inscribed server.